# Couldn't load project Pods.xcodeproject (after Stripe Pod upgrade)

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, stripe-payments

Pods project cannot be opened after upgrading the Stripe iOS SDK version and running pod install

I've summarized the information in this issue already:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6722

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting Xcode, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating a single pod. It should overwrite the older Pod project file.
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but in case anyone comes across this like I did, I deleted the pod folder and reinstalled it (for react native) but my permissions were changed. The fix was to reapply read/write permissions to the pod folder and applying that to enclosed items.

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible to say what's going on here without seeing some Xcode errors. After upgrading what errors are you seeing, etc? Stripe support can help with this kind of question directly: https://support.stripe.com/email/login